# no sound when I restart ubuntu cosmic (system76 box)

Tags: audio, alsa, ubuntu-18.10

I'm having this problem that I lose sound when I restart my computer (It's a system76 box with system76's kernel and goodies). I checked this page https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/ and the problem is solved by running `sudo alsa force-reload`, but I have to do it every time I'm already on my kde session (I installed kde-full). Is there a way to avoid me from having to do it every time?

As a little update, when I run alsamixer (even when I get no sound on kde), it displays the sound card:

`┌────────────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.1.6 ──────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA Intel PCH                                                  F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Realtek ALC269VC                                               F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All                             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Master [dB gain: -15,75]                                       Esc: Exit               │`